# How does method without a name works in jBuilder(RoR)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How does the following line of code work with [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) in ruby on rails:

```
json.(institute, :id, :name, :title, :updated_at)
```

There is no method name in the call. Can anybody explain what is going on behind the scenes here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code will call the method named `call` on the object `json`, here is an example:

```
class Test
  def call(*args)
    puts args.inspect
  end
end

t = Test.new

t.(:something, 1, 2)

=> [:something, 1, 2]
```

You can get a similar effect by using a `method_missing` method as well.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere? Is it a ruby thing or some shiny behavior from activesupport?

Comment: The beavior comes from just plain ruby. I can't find a good documentation source for the complete behavior, but this link contains the offical information on `method_missing`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what happens, although I would have loved to read about how it works.